# How to move around in ex mode in vim?

Tags: vim

I wrote a short script to generate tag files for my project. The only problem I have is the last argument which is supposed to be vim ex mode command. My question is how can I tell vim to move to line i and character j in ex mode. Alternatively I know the word a location j.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `cursor()` function:

> Positions the cursor at the column (byte count) {col} in the line {lnum}.

E.g `:call cursor(3,5)` will position your cursor to line 3 col 5.

For more detailed usage please read `:h cursor(`

Another possibility is using `:normal` command: `:norm! 3G5|`